Task user is showing as ONLINE under task summary table in business central of jbpm and status is active even after a real user completes it
I have a process in which there is task that is fetched, started and completed by api calls. Even after these API is triggered and task is completed by a active user the task summary shows the user name as ONLINE and not the actual userid who worked on the task. The task status is still active
Can you please help me understand why and how can a task be assigned to ONLINE. How is this a user?
